# Relation between metric tensor and second fundamental form

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors

I'm confused with these definitions. The metric of certain space and the second fundamental form seem to be the same object.

I don't know what else to say, this is a pretty straight forward question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *first* fundamental form and the metric tensor are indeed one and the same. The second fundamental form is not. It's a sort of derivative of the metric tensor.

Comment: Thank you for confirming this! I actually meant the first fundamental form :)